# Bind Spring Boot application name to rootProject.name from Gradle?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, application-name

I would like to set the application name in Spring Boot to the value from `rootProject.name`. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot reads the application name from the configuration property `spring.application.name`. Gradle can generate a configuration file containing that property.

Put in the `src/main/resources/application.properties` file:

```bash
spring.application.name=${rootProject.name}
```

Add the Gradle task:

```bash
processResources {
  filesMatching("application.properties") {
    expand project.properties
  }
}
```